# How to manipulate Blueimp Fileupload sequentialUploads upload order?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I'm using [blueimp/fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for uploading multiple images. Here is my init:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    maxFileSize: 20000000,
    acceptFileTypes: /^image\/(jpe?g|png)$/i,
    sequentialUploads: true,
    add: this.add,
    change: this.change
})

function change(e, data) {
    data.files.sort((a,b) => {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    })
},

function add(e, data) {
    data.submit();
},
```

And on the server side I have a `php` function that uploads each file to an AWS bucket.

The files hit the server in a random order. I've looked at the timestamp and if I was to upload:

```
[
    { "img_1.jpg", 60kb },
    { "img_2.jpg", 68kb },
    { "img_3.jpg", 40kb },
]
```

They would hit the server in this order `img_3.jpg` then `img_1.jpg` then `img_2.jpg`.

Is there a way to add a `setTimeout` delay, or add a queue that will wait for the response from the first file before it tried to upload the next one?

Comment: Side-note: your regex is silly. You've matched "jpg" 3 different ways, and "png" twice. You don't need to re-list them, you've already got the `/i` case-insensitive modifier.

Comment: @mpen thank you, fixed it.

Comment: I don't know how to do what you're asking with bluimp, but it's certainly possible in general. You wouldn't use setTimeout, you just wouldn't start the next upload until the first one completes. Blueimp probably has some sort of "complete" event hook.

Comment: @mpen I've been staring at their documentation for the last 2 hours, I'm starting to feel retarded. I was hoping, someone with fresh eyes/better knowledge of the library can help.

Comment: You can [programatically trigger an upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#programmatic-file-upload). There's `drop` and `change` events for when the user adds a file. Grab the `data.files`, shift off the first [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and tell Bluimp to upload it. When the `complete` event fires, shift off the next element in the array and upload it too.